# Trying to install Visual studio 2022 without admin rights

Tags: visual-studio, uac

I'm trying to give a way for end users to install visual studio professional 2022 without admin rights in an entreprise context (computers managed by intune).

To do that i created a policy in intune with parameter AllowStandardUserControl with value 2 like described here : [configure-policies-for-enterprise-deployments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/configure-policies-for-enterprise-deployments?view=vs-2022)

In registry, in

> HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\VisualStudio\setup

i have a key *AllowStandardUserControl* with value 2.

But when i try to execute vs_professional.exe, i have UAC.
So how can i used this functionnality to install or modify visual studio without admin right?

i try to download vs_professional.exe from microsoft and execute it but, UAC is prompting me for admin rights.

Is someone use this way to install?

Comment: That page is about administrative installs (e.g. company-wide). It doesn't really apply to single-user installations. You cannot update any value in HKLM without admin rights, but apparently you where able to set that key, so do you _have_ admin rights?

Comment: Hello, i'm on an entreprise context and use intune to put policies. I try to give a way to my end users to install VS Pro with no admin rights

Comment: Then please update your question accordingly. There's currently no mentioning that you're trying to do this for _other_ users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found by myself.
When policy is configured, installer must be installed with admin rights.
And since version 17.8, it's possible to install only the installer by using

> vs_setup.exe install ––installeronly [--passive] [--quiet]

After that, installer UI can be executed as a standard user.
A remark, binaries are always download by system account so, if you are behind a proxy, you will have to authorized it or create a offline repo